# Error en conexión php y mysql

Tags: php

[image: DbConnect.php junto con Constants.php]Me da este error, soy muy algo nuevo en esto y ya intente de todo pero no funciona :( ¿qué puede ser?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\includes\DbOperations.php:16
>
> Stack trace:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\v1\registerUser.php(19): DbOperations->createUser('eduartte', 'd41d8cd98f00b20...', 'eduar@udavinci....')
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\includes\DbOperations.php on line 16

```
<?php
 class DbOperations{

     private $con;

     function _construct(){

         require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

         $db = new DbConnect();

         $this->con = $db->connect();
     }
     function createUser($username, $password, $email){
         $password = md5($pass);
16>  $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`
         , `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?,?);");
         $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);

         if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
     }

 }

?>
*


<?php

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(
        isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['password']) and
        isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        //operate the data further
        $db = new DbOperations();

        if($db->createUser(
            $_POST['username'],
            $_POST['password'],
19>         $_POST['email']
            )){ 
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
    }else {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Some error ocurred please try again";
        }
    }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>*
```

class DbConnect{

```
private $con;

function_construct(){

}

function connect(){

    include_once dirname(__FILE__)).'/Constants.php';
    $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo"Failed to connect with database}".mysqli_connect_err();
}
```

retun $this->con;

}
?

define('DB_NAME','android');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

?>>

Comment: El error `Call to a member function prepare() on null ` indica que tu conexión no se está creando corrrectamente. Quizá aquí no esté la ruta correcta: `require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';` para depurar prueba a poner la ruta absoluta de tu archivo DbConnect.php, revisa el errorlog, quizá te diga más cosas. Y me parece extraño que más abajo hagas un include `DbOperations.php` ¿es otro archivo que se llama igual que tu clase o estás autoincluyendo al mismo archivo? ¿Estás usando PDO o MySQLi?

Comment: por eso necesitamos el DBConnect.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las consultas preparadas se trabajan de la siguiente manera, por cierto que PHP estas usando?

```
<?php
 class DbOperations{

     private $con;

     function _construct(){

         require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

         $db = new DbConnect();

         $this->con = $db->connect();
     }
     function createUser($username, $password, $email){
         $password = md5($pass);
16>  $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`
         , `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, :var1, :var2, :var3);");
         $stmt->execute(array(':var1' => $tuvariable1, ':var2' => $tuvariable2 , ':var3' => $tuvariable3));

         if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
     }

 }

?>
*


<?php

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(
        isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['password']) and
        isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        //operate the data further
        $db = new DbOperations();

        if($db->createUser(
            $_POST['username'],
            $_POST['password'],
19>         $_POST['email']
            )){ 
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
    }else {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Some error ocurred please try again";
        }
    }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Por cierto sube el codigo de tu archivo DbConnect.php.

Comment: me refiero a la version de PHP que estas utilizando amigo, independientemente del editor que estes usando.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjQaV062aE_CW68xgXdYFpV&v=8Ou1ERM2MOw no se que version es, ya que estoy sacando el codigo de aqui

Comment: Usas xampp, wampp ?? mira para que te quede facil crea un archivo con el nombre que quieras .php y dentro pones el siguiente codigo <?php echo 'Versión actual de PHP: ' . phpversion(); echo phpversion('tidy');
?>

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.phpversion.php

Comment: uso xampp con el PHP Version 7.1.1 y arriba puse la imagen de los dos archivos faltantes.

Comment: cambien las comillas ( ` ) por apostrofes, ( ' ) para ello en cada archivo da Control + H y reemplaza todo